# Distinct of List <T> not workiong

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, collections

I have this class with comparer

```
public partial class CityCountryID :IEqualityComparer<CityCountryID>
{

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CityCountryID left, CityCountryID right)
    {
        if ((object)left == null && (object)right == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if ((object)left == null || (object)right == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return left.City.Trim().TrimEnd('\r', '\n') == right.City.Trim().TrimEnd('\r', '\n') 
            && left.CountryId == right.CountryId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CityCountryID obj)
    {
        return (obj.City + obj.CountryId).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I Tried using Hashset and Distinct but neither one is working. i did not want to do this in db as the list was too big and too for everrrrrrrr. why is this not working in c#? **i want to get a unique country, city list.**

```
            List<CityCountryID> CityList = LoadData("GetCityList").ToList();
            //var unique = new HashSet<CityCountryID>(CityList);
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Completed/ Checking Duplicates");
            List<CityCountryID> unique = CityList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried by just overriding object's `Equals` and `GetHashcode`?

Comment: @I4V that is what i have done above? are you seeing something diffrent?

Comment: Justin you are implementing `IEqualityComparer` interface, not the same.

Comment: @JustinHomes in fact you have to add `override` keywords here, overriding the 2 `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or pass in a `different object implementing IEqualityComparer` into `Distinct`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to implment the interface [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) not `IEqualityComparer<T>` (Be sure to read the documentation, especially the "**Notes to Implementers**" section!). IEqualityComparer is when you want to use a custom comparer other than the default one built in to the class.

Also you need to make the changes that [Jon mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685987/80274) about `GetHashCode` not matching `Equals`

Comment: Well spotted - I'd missed that entirely!

Answer (score 5):

Your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods aren't consistent. In `Equals`, you're trimming the city name -  but in `GetHashCode` you're not. That means two equal values can have different hash codes, violating the normal contract.

That's the first thing to fix. I would suggest trimming the city names in the database itself for sanity, and then removing the `Trim` operations in your `Equality` check. That'll make things a lot simpler.

The second is work out *why* it was taking a long time in the database: I'd strongly *expect* it to perform better in the database than locally, especially if you have indexes on the two fields.

The next is to consider making your type immutable if at all possible. It's generally a bad idea to allow mutable properties of an object to affect equality; if you change an equality-sensitive property of an object after using it as a key in a dictionary (or after adding it to a `HashSet`) you may well find that you can't retrieve it again, even using the exact same reference.

EDIT: Also, as Scott noted, you *either* need to pass in an `IEqualityComparer` to perform the equality comparison *or* make your type override the normal `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. At the moment you're half way between the two (implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`, but not actually providing a comparer as an argument to `Distinct` or the `HashSet` constructor). In general it's unusual for a type to implement `IEqualityComparer` for itself. Basically you *either* implement a "natural" equality check in the type *or* you implement a standalone equality check in a type implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`. You don't *have* to implement `IEquatable<T>` - just overriding the normal `Equals(object)` method will work - but it's generally a good idea to implement `IEquatable<T>` at the same time.

As an aside, I would also suggest computing a hash code without using string concatenation. For example:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 31 + CountryId.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + City.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: i do have indexes on both fields but i am running by db locally on my laptop vm which could be why its not as fast.

Comment: @JustinHomes: I'd still expect it to be faster than pulling *all* the data down and then doing the same thing yourself. Maybe you should ask another question showing the SQL you've tried.

Comment: my sql is pretty straight fwd i have Index asc on both fields
Select Distinct  City, CountryId from CityCode ; i also have a primary id on this table. there are duplicates on this table due to non unique city, country which is what i am trying to fix

Comment: Could I ask about the `GetHashCode()` you use, why is the `hash` intialized with `17` (not any other?) and the next steps? Thank you!

Comment: i have 4 million records on that table when running mysql it times out after 6 mins. when i run it from c# it does this in 30 sec.

Comment: @JustinHomes: I'd still expect MySQL to be able to do it quickly... I still think it's worth asking as a separate question.